# ¿Para qué sirven las clases locales en Java?

Tags: java, clase-anidada

He encontrado la documentación de Java sobre clases locales y no encuentro su utilidad. Es decir, si meto una clase en otra no debería provocarme un error.

Me refiero a esto: [Inner Class Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

¿Podrían explicarme su utilidad y proporcionarme algún ejemplo que no me diera error al tener dos clases en el mismo archivo?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo en el que te de error? Así lo podremos ver más fácilmente a que te refieres.

Answer (score 5):

Son clases internas y no te debe dar error. El enlace que has puesto lo define perfectamente. Me temo que será un problema de cómo colocas las llaves. Si tu error es que tu IDE dice que la clase tiene que tener el mismo nombre que el fichero .java fíjate que tu clase interna esté dentro de las llaves de la clase que define el fichero, debería estar a la misma altura que su constructor para que me explique.

Su utilidad está clara, si necesitas una clase pero sólo la vas a usar en una única clase, puedes hacerla interna.

**EDITO:**

Para agregar tu ejemplo y que te quede más claro:

```
public class Coche {
    String marca;
    Motor motor;

    public Coche (String marca, Motor motor) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.motor = motor;
        System.out.println("Escribe la marca del carro:");
    }

    public void mostrarCoche(){
        System.out.println("Coche marca: " + marca + " | motor: " + motor);
    }

    public class Motor {
        String tipoMotor;

        public Motor (){
            tipoMotor = "Uno Cualquiera";
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return tipoMotor;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hola Awes0meM4n entiendo que sirve como una clase dentro de una clase ? pero mi pregunta es me podias dar un ejemplo en la vida diaria del desarrollo en que cosa lo podria implementar eso no entiendo

Comment: Imagina que tienes una clase vehículo y necesitas implementar otra clase motor. Si sólo vas a usar la clase motor en la clase vehículo, no hace falta que hagas otro archivo .java para la clase motor, puedes hacerla interna y te queda el paquete más compacto.

Comment: Por cierto @sommer0123 , fuera del tema y como te he visto que has intentado notificar más de un comentario a usuarios en concreto, si quieres hacer eso debes poner el nombre de usuario precedido de una @ y todo junto. Puedes verlo en la etiqueta que pone "ayuda" junto a los comentarios que escribes.

Comment: haaaaaa okey aver are un ejemplo aver si es como lo comentas :

Comment: package ClassLocales;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClaseMain {
    
public static void main(String[]args){
    
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Escribe la marca del carro:");
    
    
    
    
    
}

    public class metodos{
        
        public static String Carro(String carro){
            
            return carro;
            }
        
    }
}

Comment: @sommer0123 Yo me refería a algo como lo que he añadido a la respuesta. Creo que ya queda claro, en este supuesto `Motor` sólo hace falta para la clase `Coche`.

Comment: No sé si el ejemplo `Coche` y `Motor` sea el más apropiado =\

Answer (score 5):

Según la documentación de Oracle: Las clases anidadas permiten agrupar de forma lógica clases que únicamente serán utilizadas en un solo lugar, incrementando el uso de la encapsulación y creando código más entendible y fácil de mantener.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html

Answer (score 2):

Las respuestas de [@Garrizano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/37698/227) y [@Awes0meM4n](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/37696/227) cubren el concepto. Lo que falta es explicar cuándo son útiles estas clases. Veamos cada clase de acuerdo a su tipo:

1. Clases internas estáticas

Se usan principalmente por orden en tus componentes. Suele indicar que la clase está asociada íntimamente con la clase que lo contiene. El hecho de ser `static` significa que **no necesita compartir nada con la clase que lo contiene**. Es por ello que estas clases se pueden crear sin necesidad de que exista una instancia de la clase que la contiene.

Ejemplo:

```
public class Persona {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;

    //constructor, getters y setters...
    //método toString
    public String toString() {
        return id + " " + nombre;
    }
}

public class Comparadores {
    public static class ComparadorPersonaPorId implements Comparator<Persona> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Persona p1, Persona p2) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(p1);
            Objects.requireNonNull(p2);
            return Integer.compare(p1.getId(), p2.getId());
        }
    }

    public static class ComparadorPersonaPorNombre implements Comparator<Persona> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Persona p1, Persona p2) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(p1);
            Objects.requireNonNull(p2);
            //puede que hayas importado alguna librería con este utilitario
            //o que lo crees por tu cuenta
            //el código de compare de cadenas es algo como
            // return s1 == null && s2 == null ? 0 :
            //            s1 == null ? -1 :
            //            s2 == null ? 1 : s1.compareTo(s2);
            return StringUtils.compare(p1.getNombre(), p2.getNombre());
        }
    }
}

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Persona> personas = Arrays.asList(
            new Persona(1, "Jose"),
            new Persona(3, "Gabriela"),
            new Persona(2, "Alvin"));
        System.out.println(personas);
        personas.sort(new Comparadores.ComparatorPersonaPorId());
        System.out.println(personas);
        personas.sort(new Comparadores. ComparadorPersonaPorNombre());
        System.out.println(personas);
    }
}
```

Ejemplos en el JDK: [`LinkedList#Node`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java) (línea 970), [`HashMap#Node`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) (línea 278), [`Arrays#ArrayList`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java) (línea 3800).

2. Clases internas no estáticas

Al igual que las clases internas estáticas, se usan principalmente por orden en tus componentes. El hecho de no ser estática significa que **puede acceder al estado de la clase que la contiene**. Esto es una gran ventaja cuando diseñas clases de lógica de negocio que no necesitan ser expuestas al mundo exterior.

Ejemplo adaptado de una clase que implementé hace tiempo (escrito para Java 6):

```
public interface BonoService {
    void validaBonos(String excel);
    //entre otros métodos...
}

public class BonoServiceImpl implements BonoService {

    private BonoDao bonoDao;
    private ClienteService clienteService;
    private int numeroHilos;

    @Override
    public void validaBonos(String excel) {
        List<Bono> listaBonos = obtieneBonos(excel);
        //la acción de validar cada Bono toma mucho tiempo
        //así que vamos a procesarlos en hilos
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numeroHilos);
        for (Bono bono : listaBonos) {
            es.submit(new ValidadorBono(bono));
        }
        es.shutdown();
        while (!es.isTerminated()) {
            //esperar que termine de validar todos los bonos...
        }
    }

    private List<Bono> obtieneBonos(String excel) {
        //lee un archivo Excel en base a la ruta
        //convierte cada línea del archivo en una instancia de Bono
        //devuelve una lista con los bonos encontrados
    }

    private class ValidadorBono implements Runnable {
        Bono bono;
        public ValidadorBono(Bono bono) {
            this.bono = bono;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //implementación de validación de objeto Bono
            //ejemplo de una regla de validacion
            //Como se menciona, se pueden acceder a los atributos
            //y métodos de la clase contenedora
            //por ejemplo, el siguiente código hace referencia al
            //atributo clienteService que se encuentra en la clase superior
            if (BonoServiceImpl.this.clienteService
                //el de aquí es un método del objeto
                .existeCliente(bono.getCliente()) {
                //continuar...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ejemplos en el JDKL [`ArrayList#Itr`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) (línea 825).

3. Clases internas locales

Similares a las clases internas, la diferencia es que estas no están a nivel de toda la clase, sino a nivel de un solo método o porción de código. Este tipo de clases son comúnmente la implementación de una interfaz o la extensión de una clase puesta en el método. Este es un ejemplo más común y de los más utilizados en Java.

Ejemplo:

```
public class EjercicioHilos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //usaremos ExecutorService nuevamente
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            //Runnable es una interfaz
            //las llaves luego de new Runnable()
            //indican que se va a escribir la implementación
            //de manera directa aquí en el método

            //las clases locales no pueden reasignar variables
            //que pertenecen al método
            //por ello, para usar una variable ella debe ser
            //declarada como final
            //por ello no podemos pasar "i" directamente
            //sino mediante una variable "final int x"
            final int x = i;
            es.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(x);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Nota: todos estos ejemplos pueden ser re escritos usando la nueva característica de Java 8: lambdas. El código es más conciso y directo.

Answer (score 0):

Otro ejemplo de uso:

Algo que quieres que se ejecute 1 única y exclusiva vez.

Haces un juego, y quieres guardar los 10 resultados más altos en un archivo de texto.

Puedes crearte una clase interna en la clase encargada de manejar los resultados. O incluso, una clase local "creadoraDeLog" dedicada a la creación del archivo dentro del método de escribir un resultado dentro del archivo.

Si el jugador ha alcanzado un puesto dentro del top ten, ejecuta el método de inscribir record. Y dentro de ese inscribir record, si el archivo no existe... me creo un objeto de la clase CreadorDeLog y ejecuto su método "crearArchivo".

Para qué vas a querer una clase accesible desde todo el código que sea capaz de crear archivos si el juego en sí no la necesita, y tampoco la necesitas para iniciar una partida (normalmente los records se miran después, y si el usuario borró el archivo de records o acaba de empezar a jugar por 1ª vez en ese ordenador, de todas formas no iba a poder ver ningun record antes de jugar). Así pues, la clase encargada de crear archivos es tontería que pueda ser accesible desde ningún otro sitio que no sea el interior del método guardarRecord.

Además, esto también optimiza bastante la memoria. Cuando un objeto es instanciado, se crea un espacio en memoria con todos sus campos, constructores y métodos. el método donde se ha instanciado ese objeto termina, el objeto desaparece y ese espacio de memoria se limpia y queda libre.

Answer (score 0):

Las clases internas locales son las clases internas que se definen dentro de un bloque. Generalmente, este bloque es un cuerpo de método. A veces, este bloque puede ser un ciclo for, o una cláusula if.