# ¿Dominios hechos con IP?

Tags: web

## Introducción

Recientemente, me encontré con una página que no tenía un dominio común, era parecido a un IP y no tenía algún `.com` o cualquier terminación común. La dirección es [esta](http://85.152.37.8/recursos/mujeres/archivos/sigloxix/avances_cientificos_del_siglo_xix.htm).

```
http://85.152.37.8/recursos/mujeres/archivos/sigloxix/avances_cientificos_del_siglo_xix.htm
```

Como ven, tiene como index un *85.152.37.8* y esto es lo que me intriga.

Ya intente buscar en su `.html` alguna etiqueta que me diga quién es el creador o algún dato útil, pero no hay nada; al parecer es una estructura muy básica, llena de `<p>` y otras etiquetas básicas de `html`.

### Pregunta

¿Qué es este dominio?

¿Cómo puedo hacer o adquirir uno como este? (al menos como se llaman para buscar como hacer uno, luego postear el procedimiento aquí)

Comment: Me parece mas a que es un servidor web accedido por dirección IP y no por dominio

Comment: En lo que dices acerca de obtener un dominio, estos simplemente necesitas un servidor y accederlo directamente por la ip

Comment: El servidor lo puedo obtener en hostinger, pero como se hace eso del ip?

Comment: En lo que te refieres a lo de la ip simplemente es configurar tu servidor web por ejemplo apache y accederlo por la dirección IP la que te proporciona tu proveedor

Comment: Interesante, entonces buscaré mas al respecto

Comment: Estoy notando que mi ip está asociada a un dominio de Gateway :\

Comment: Si ya sabes que es un IP, me sorprende que preguntas por dominios "hechos de IP". Un IP es una dirección única en el internet, un dominio solamente es un nombre  reservado que puede representar un o más IP (incluyendo sus subdominios). Lo encuentro valido de responder a su propia pregunta, siempre mientras tanto tienes una buena respuesta, pero aquí estas mandando la gente al desierto.

Answer (score 1):

IP y dominio son cosas completamente distintos, y en tu caso el dato interesante es la definicion de un URI, en que se anota protocolo ("http://"), host en forma de IP (v4:"127.0.0.1" o v6:"::1") o dominio (en formato subdominio.dominio.tld como "ras.nte.to") seguido por una ruta separado por "/".

Ejemplos:

```
http://ras.nte.to/camino/a/la/confusion
rtmp://127.0.0.1/ruta/video/tutorial.flv
https://[::1]/ipv6/test/doc.pdf
```

El hecho que en un IPv4 los 4 bytes estan separados por puntos no lo hace un dominio.

En [Sistema de nombres de dominio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_nombres_de_dominio) se explica en forma aceptable todo lo que el usuario básico tiene que saber.

Comment: Creo que el comentario de "esta pregunta es más para Wikipedia" es alturado. Recuerda que no naciste sabiéndolo todo, así como en algún momento te mencionaron algún término como DNS y no tenías idea de qué era. Sí, se puede buscar información al respecto y salen enlaces como wikipedia, pero si vamos a ayudar a alguien en este sitio, tratemos de hacerlo pensando en ayudar y no en decir "revisa aquí", lo último luce más como comentario. Podrías colocar "<aquí> (enlace) hay más información".

Comment: No lo veo alturado, y no fue la intención.Wikipedia. Las preguntas y respuestas en stackoverflow son más enfocado en problemas concretas, mientras Wikipedia se trata más de conocimiento general. No creo que es necesario de copiar y pegar informaciónes de otros lugares aquí si ya existen en otra parte. Por supuesto no nací sabiendo todo, incluso aprendí algunas cosas de Wikipedia por el camino ;) El usuario en este caso hizo una pregunta apto para despistar el lector para luego responder a si mismo de nuevo en una forma apto para despistar del hecho que un IP no es un formato de un dominio.

Comment: [Esta pregunta de Java](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/37695/227) es sobre conceptos, que [también están en Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class#Types_of_nested_classes_in_Java). El sitio se enfoca en todo lo asociado a programación y [otros temas que decidimos en comunidad](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/161/227). Y no se copia/pega contenido de otro lado pero a veces esto es necesario como parte de la explicación que brindamos (citas). Los enlaces justo sirven para eso: para ahondar más en el concepto. Si no, según entiendo de lo que dices, deberíamos responder con enlaces

Comment: Entiendo tu punto de vista, y como parte de la comunidad me reservo el derecho de opinar distinto, pero he editado mi respuesta respetando los tuyos :)

Answer (score -2):

Es el ip del dominio en sí, cada dominio tiene su propio ip, pero se transforma a letras para que nos sea mas fácil encontrar y recordar las paginas.

Si sacamos el host de ese ip quedaría algo como esto: `cm-staticIP-85-152-37-8.telecable.es`

Pagina para convertir los host a ip y viceversa: https://www.cdmon.com/es/conversor-host-ip

Comment: Un dominio registrado no necesariamente tiene que tener IP asociados. Tampoco existe un algoritmo de transformar un IP en letras. Tu respuesta implica eso, quizás encuentras una forma mas precisa de presentar tu idea.